# Drop rows using conditionals pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm aiming to drop rows in a pandas df where specific rows appear out of sequence. Using below, the beginning of a sequence is outlined by `Start` in `Item`. The sequence finishes before the subsequent `Start` value.

I want to remove rows that are equal to `A` or `B`, where a given sequence does contain any string from `End` (before the next `Start`).

Note: The number of rows that contain `A` or `B` before the next `Start` is random.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Num' : [1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17],
    'Item' : ['Start','A','B','B','G','Start','A','B','B','A','X','Start','A','H'],        
    })


Val = ['A','B']

End = ['X','Y','Z']

g = df['Item'].isin(Val).groupby(df['Item'].eq('Start').cumsum())
cond1 = g.transform('sum')>=1
cond2 = g.transform('idxmax')
out = df[cond1 & (df.index<=cond2)]
```

df:

```
    Num   Item
0     1  Start
1     2      A # No value in End before next Start. Drop
2     3      B # No value in End before next Start. Drop
3     4      B # No value in End before next Start. Drop
4     6      G
5     7  Start
6     9      A # X appears before next Start. Keep
7    10      B # X appears before next Start. Keep
8    12      B # X appears before next Start. Keep
9    13      A # X appears before next Start. Keep
10   14      X
11   15  Start
12   16      A # No value in End before next Start. Drop
13   17      H
```

intended output:

```
    Num   Item
0     1  Start
4     6      G
5     7  Start
6     9      A 
7    10      B 
8    12      B 
9    13      A 
10   14      X
11   15  Start
13   17      H
```

Comment: can you try to explain it better? what do you need ```Val``` for?

Comment: I need them to explain the `End` values. But if there is no `End` value within a given sequence, I need to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here is a working solution. It uses the starts to define even and odd groups and drops values from Val matching even groups.

If this is not what you want, please provide a counter-example and the matching expected output.

```
starts = df['Item'].eq('Start')
to_drop = starts.cumsum().add(1).mul(~starts)%2*df['Item'].isin(Val)
df.loc[to_drop[to_drop.eq(0)].index]
```

output:

```
    Num   Item
0     1  Start
1     2      A
2     3      B
3     4      X
4     6  Start
8    12      G
9    13  Start
10   14      A
11   15      B
12   17      Y
13   18      Z
```

Comment: I've updated the example input. The number of rows that could be dropped is random. So I need something more robust.